# Does my service have access to my static classes?

Tags: android, service, scope

I should use a long-running listener service in my project which runs after the destruction of main thread. Now, my question is:
Does this service have access to my static methods?
I have defined all Data related functions in a class. Now, my listener service should receive data and insert it into Database. Can I use my static methods or I have to copy&paste necessary functions in that service class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java there are no "static classes" properly speaking. I understand you mean "static methods". If these classes are bundled on the same APK, then yes, they're accessible by your `Service` (given they have the correct visibility).

Comment: Thank you ^____^ ... you are right...I edited my post...I meant methods.